# Dot Net new console creation on VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

Whenever I go to vscode's terminal and type

`dotnet new console`

it gives me an error

```
Error while processing file /content/ConsoleApplication-CSharp/Company.ConsoleApplication1.csproj
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/Users/zohaibarsalan/Documents/programming/c#/learningc#/learningc#.csproj' is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Operation not permitted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.File.Create(String path)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Utils.PhysicalFileSystem.CreateFile(String path)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Core.Util.Orchestrator.ProcessFile(IFile sourceFile, String sourceRel, String targetDir, IGlobalRunSpec spec, IProcessor fallback, IEnumerable`1 fileGlobProcessors, IReadOnlyList`1 locOperations)
```

how can I fix this?
I have installed dot net from Microsoft, so do I need to delete it, and if so how?
or do I have to change some settings?
This also happens on the terminal.
BTW this is on a MAC

Comment: I had the same problem. I had create new cs console app and past all the cs script in it.

Comment: Try to remove the _#_ from the folder name. Maybe is an issue with special charters.

Comment: did you install using admin account rights of the OS.